# ¿Cómo puedo borrar datos, tablas y stored procedures de una base de datos?

Tags: base-de-datos, sql-server-2019

Necesito tener mi base de datos como recién creada, ya tengo algunas tablas relacionadas con datos y algunos stored procedures. No aplica la opción de eliminar y volver a crear la base de datos.

Comment: Hola Luigi, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y obtengas una mejor respuesta, y de paso evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada, y de paso, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Varios han probado con buenos resultados la función **sp_MSForEachTable**.

Con **DELETE**

```
-- Deshabilitar integridad referencial
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL' 
GO 

EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'DELETE FROM ?' 
GO 

-- Habilitar integridad referencial
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL' 
GO
```

Con **TRUNCATE**

```
-- Deshabilitar integridad referencial
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL' 
GO 

EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'TRUNCATE TABLE ?' 
GO  

-- Habilitar integridad referencial
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL' 
GO
```

Recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada si solventa tu duda.

Answer (score -1):

Lo que deberías hacer es deshabilitar las llaves foráneas.

```
ALTER TABLE [TABLA] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [ALL|CONSTRAINT_NAME]
```

después eliminar los registros que ya no necesitas.

```
DELETE FROM [TABLA]
WHERE <Condición>
```

y después vuelves a habilitar las llaves foráneas

```
ALTER TABLE [TABLA] WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT [ALL|CONSTRAINT_NAME]
```